# Does SELECT FOR UPDATE in MySQL have a limit?

Tags: mysql

In our application, we are using SELECT FOR UPDATE statement to ensure locking for our entities from other threads. One of our original architects who implemented this logic put a comment in our wiki that MySQL has a limit of 200 for select for update statements. I could not find anything like this anywhere on the internet. Does anyone know if this is true and if so is there any way we can increase the limit?

Comment: Unless your developer can cite a source for that claim, I have a feeling that information is false. Try it with a higher limit to find out. As a note, anything that locks rows is usually a bad plan, so try and engineer your code to avoid doing this whenever possible. Use atomic update statements.

Comment: We have some dependencies for different workflow events and to ensure that another workflow event for the same applicant does not run until a previous one is complete, we create an entry for that applicant in a table and we issue Select for Update against the applicant ID. So any other events for the same applicant needs to wait until this one is complete. We are reading these events from a JMS queue and the max is set to 200 because apparently Select for update has some limit of 200 which is what I am trying to find out why and can that be increased

Comment: So we are unable to scale beyond 200 concurrent requests at any point in time which creates a problem at peak volume.

Comment: "apparently Select for update has some limit of 200" is not a substantiated claim. Unless you can source this or prove it experimentally I'm not going to believe it's true and you should ignore it. That your entire application has been architected around this unproven limit is concerning as well.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for SELECT FOR UPDATE is used is for Concurrency Prevention in the case when two users are currently trying to access the same data in the same time. If the users, however, try to update the data there will be a serious problem in the database.

In some Database Systems this problem can affect database integrity in a serious way. To help prevent concurrency problem, some Database Management Systems like SQL Server and MySQL use **locking** in most cases to prevent serious data integrity problems from occuring.

These locks delay the execution of the committed transaction if it conflicts the transaction that is already running.

In SQL Server or MySQL SELECT FOR UPDATE queries are used when the transaction is committed or rolled back.

In MySQL, however, the transaction records are allocated to individual MySQL servers for a minimum total number of transactions in the cluster.

MySQL uses high level datbase algorithm that makes up this formula:

TotalNoOfConcurrentTransactions = (maximum number of tables accessed in any single transaction + 1) * number of SQL nodes. 
Each data node can handle TotalNoOfConcurrentTransactions / number of data nodes. Each and every Network Database (NDB) Cluster has 4 data nodes.

The result of the above formula is expressed as MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions / 4.

In MySQL Documentation, they provided an example using 10 SQL nodes using a cluster in 10 tables in 11 transaction that resulted in 275 as MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions.

LIMIT in SELECT FOR UPDATE is possibly used for number of rows affected during update.

I am not sure probably your architects made use of the figure above according to MySQL Documentation.

Please check the link below for more information.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxnoofconcurrentoperations

Comment: We do not have a clustered MySQL. It is just one MySQL server.